# Винегрет и вино

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Можно ли отнести слова винегрет и вино к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 1):

Этимологически - можно, но родственные связи двух слов просматриваются только за пределами русского языка. Слово транскрибировано из французского vinaigrette, где оно означает *соус*, содержащий уксус (фр. vinaigre), сейчас это распространённая заправка для овощных салатов, на основе оливкового масла и винного уксуса. Слово *уксус*, в свою очередь, составлено во французском из корней слов "вино" и "кислый". Поэтому в слове "винегрет можно усмотреть следы латинского корня слова, означающего "вино".